# Can I grab some specific third api data as an additional property to my django api view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an api view which fetches data from its model. I want this api view to have an additional value from third party api. Here is `views.py` which grabs all of its model properties.

```
  @api_view(
    ["GET"],
)
def business_asset_risk_details(request):
    res = models.BusinessImpact.objects.all().values(
        "hierarchy",
        "business_assets",
        "asset_name",
        "vendors",
        "product",
        "version",
        "cpe",
        "asset_type",
        "asset_categorization",
        "_regulations",
        "asset_risk",
    )
    return Response({"business_impact_details": res})
```

Here is third party api view fetching a specific values of it's own.

```
@api_view(
    ["GET"],
)
def cve_summery(request, key):
    r = requests.get(
        "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0?cpeMatchString={}".format(
            key)
    )
    if r.status_code == 200:
        result = []
        res = r.json().get("result").get("CVE_Items")
        for rs in res:
            data = {
                "VulnID": rs.get("cve").get("CVE_data_meta").get("ID"),
                "Summery": rs.get("cve").get("description").get("description_data"),
                "exploitabilityScore": rs.get("impact")
                .get("baseMetricV2")
                .get("exploitabilityScore"),
                "severity": rs.get("impact").get("baseMetricV2").get("severity"),
                "impactScore": rs.get("impact").get("baseMetricV2").get("impactScore"),
            }
            result.append(data)
        return Response(result)
    return Response("error happend", r.status_code)
```

The logic here is, I want `business_asset_risk_details` view to return `"severity": rs.get("impact").get("baseMetricV2").get("severity"),` from `cve_summery` view.

**NB:** THE ***KEY*** parameter in `cve_summery` view IS `cpe` of `business_asset_risk_details`

Thanks.